# Preg_Replace gives error in empty value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hello i want to use the Preg_Replace function whenever i am checking for input of user whether entered any value or not. if not gives an error message like 'Enter your name please' but instead of this i am receiving this error :

> Notice: Undefined index: buildingslabs in C:\xampp\htdocs\spdealers\Admin
>       Panel\Property_Insert_Page_exe.php on line 24

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $buildingslabs = preg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['buildingslabs']);

  if(empty($buildingslabs)
  {
    echo 'Plese Enter the Buildings Labs';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'successfully inserted';
  }
?>
```

Comment: you should always use `isset` for `Post` and `Get` values and then a check for if they are `empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset` here

```
if(isset($_POST['buildingslabs'])) {
    $buildingslabs = preg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['buildingslabs']);

    if(empty($buildingslabs)
    {
        echo 'Plese Enter the Buildings Labs';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'successfully inserted';
    }
}
```

Comment: hey guys is there any shortut for Indent code in dreamweaver.

Comment: @user2249348 I am not working on `dreamweaver` so I don't know...:(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(!empty( $_POST['buildingslabs'])){
  $buildingslabs = preg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['buildingslabs']);

  if(empty($buildingslabs)
  {
   echo 'Plese Enter the Buildings Labs';
  }
  else
  {
  echo 'successfully inserted';
  }
}
else{
echo 'Plese Enter the Buildings Labs';
}
```

Comment: This is working nic but this will be good for defining 43 variable or not ? 

        if(empty($_POST['propertyid']))
 {

        $PropertyID=preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "", $_POST['propertyid']);
 echo 'Please Recheck the Form and submitted again something is missing';

 }

 else
 {

 echo 'oK.';

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice: Undefined index: buildingslabs in C:\xampp\htdocs\spdealers\Admin        
Panel\Property_Insert_Page_exe.php on line 24
```

it shows that you're index in $_POST['buildingslabs'] is not exist. Try check your input text name.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in preg_replace.

Use

`if(empty($_POST['buildingslubs'])) $_POST['buildingslubs'] = '';`

before preg_replace begin

Comment: YOU MEAN I SHOULD DEFINE THE VARIABLES IN OPENING PORTION  {  VARIABLE IN HERE }

Comment: @user2249348 - **STOP SCREAMING!**

Comment: @user2249348 i mean you must follow the rule of initialization in all programming language

Answer (score 0):

The notice doesn't come from `preg_replace()`; rather, you're trying to access `$_POST['buildinglabs']` but the `buildinglabs` parameter is not posted.

I would turn the regular expression around and use `filter_input()`:

```
$labs = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'buildingslabs', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, [
    'options' => ['regexp' => '/^[A-Z a-z0-9]+$/'],
    'flags' => FITLER_NULL_ON_FAILURE,
]);

if ($labs !== null) {
    // do something
}
```

If the parameter is not posted (could be either GET request or something is missing from the POST), `$labs` would be `null`.

If not, the regular expression attempts to validate the whole string (from start to end), all characters being inside the given character set.